# Why study 6d SCFT, when it is 2d CFT that is well studied?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, superconformality

According to AGT correspondence, if we compactify 6d SCFT to a 4d Riemann surface, then we find that certain physical quantities of 4d QFT on this surface are related to certain properties of that surface. (More precisely, there is a correspondence between the correlation function on the surface and the partition function of the qft.)

I want to know what is special about 6d, given that CFT is usually worked out in 2d most frequently due to its mathematical well-definedness. Is there rather intuitive way to understand why it must be 6d than say 4d? I know that the existence of 6d SCFT comes from the string theory which is 11 dimensional, but I can't see how one can easily see it from that perspective.

Must be a stupid question, but is it because 6d=4d+2d, 4d being what we want and 2d being well understood so easily manipulatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CFT in 2d is relatively well understood.  CFT in higher dimension is still relatively mysterious.  Representation theoretic arguments, due mainly to Nahm, IIRC, indicate 6 is the largest dimension in which interacting SCFTs can exist, much as 10 is the largest dimension in which supergravities can exist.  This is a physics theorem, of course, so it's a mix of very solid representation theory and somewhat more caveated theorems on what sort of fields can have interactions.  So it was known that these CFTs could exist in 6d, but there weren't any constructions before string theory.

Comment: The representation theory arguments are valid for SCFTs. Whether there are CFTs in $d>6$ is an open question, much like non-SUSY CFTs in $d>4$.

Comment: Right.  That is a typo, or a think-o, but definitely not the intended statement.  Thanks.